# How to map NavArgs to NavArgument?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, navigation-framework

The issue I encountered is related to setting navigation graph programatically. What I want to achieve is to decide in `Activity` which fragment should be a start destination. What's more, each of these fragments have additional arguments.

Let's say we have such navigation graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.mypackage.Fragment1"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_fragment1">

        <argument
            android:name="argument1"
            app:argType="int" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.mypackage.Fragment2"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_fragment2">

        <argument
            android:name="argument2"
            app:argType="string" />

    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

If we use Safe Args plugin (`androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin`), two classes will be generated: `Fragment1Args` and `Fragment2Args`, both implementing `NavArgs` interface.

Now because we need to decide which fragment should became start destination, we need to make graph programatically:

```
val graph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph)
if (someCondition) {
    graph.startDestination = R.id.fragment1
} else {
    graph.startDestination = R.id.fragment2
}
navController.graph = graph
```

But Fragment1 and Fragment2 requires some additional arguments, so we need somehow to add them to graph. It turns out that graph has method `addArguments(NavArguments)`, but as you see it's not `NavArgs` interface. Question is how to set these arguments properly that Fragment1 or Fragment2 will be able to extract?

I'm using `1.0.0-rc02` version of navigation framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `<argument>` tag to your navigation XML, it is **already** creating the `NavArgument` classes when you call `inflate()`, so there's nothing you need to do to the graph in order to pass arguments to the start destination.

Instead, you should use [`setGraph(NavGraph, Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.html#setGraph(androidx.navigation.NavGraph,%20android.os.Bundle)) to set the graph and pass initial arguments to the start destination.

```
// Construct your Bundle of arguments
val bundle = bundleOf()
// set the graph with specific arguments for the start destination
navController.setGraph(graph, bundle)
```

Comment: See also the [documentation request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124153134) for ensuring that this use case is covered by the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You said: "What I want to achieve is to decide in Activity which fragment should be a start destination."

And I think you're trying to make the decision in the fragmen, which is not correct here because you didn't open the fragment yet, Thus the correct behavior is to do that in activity e.g:

```
when (someCondition) {
        TO_FRAGMENT_1-> {
            findNavController(R.id.fragment).navigate(R.id.fragment1)
        }
        TO_FRAGMENT_2-> {
            findNavController(R.id.fragment).navigate(R.id.fragment2)
        }
    }
```

And if the activity is the first activity in your app, you should use something else instead of args, e.g: `SharedPref`.

Comment: You're using some assumptions that are not in my case. First of all it doesn't matter if it's first activity, because someCondition can be value from preferences or something completely different. Secondly, you need startDestination otherwise you're app will crash with exception.

Comment: @Nominalista so what is the problem here?, I don't think the app will crash because you define the destination in activity in `onCreate` for example.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain question correctly. I was sure about the way of creating graph and deciding to which fragment it should navigate, but I didn't know how pass initial data correctly. @ianhanniballake answer explained that.